# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064(previous answer is not helping)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fix this query, but for some reason, it's throwing error.
What changes should I make ?

**Code**

```
$statement=$conn->prepare("SELECT p.productid AS productid,
                                  p.productname AS productname,
                                  t.itemid AS itemid,t.amount AS amount,
                                  t.is_completed AS is_completed,
                                  t.id AS recordid 
                           FROM products p,temporder t 
                           where p.productid=t.itemid AND is_completed = 0 
                           LIMIT 0, 30 AND t.email = ?");
$statement->execute(array($_SESSION['email']));
$rows=$statement->rowCount();//get no. of rows
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Error :**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND t.email =
>   'test@gmail.com'' at line 1

Comment: You should _read the documentation_ for the language features that you use. The syntax error in your query is trivially identifiable by reading the `SELECT` documentation. What prevented you from making this effort?

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
  where p.productid=t.itemid AND is_completed = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 AND t.email = ?
```

to

```
 where p.productid=t.itemid AND is_completed = 0 AND t.email = ? LIMIT 0, 30
```